# Web Setup - VS2022 - Hosting Bundle Prerequisites

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, web-setup-project

I want to install Hosting Bundle on relevant computer before the project is installed. However, it is not on this list.

[image]

How can I do this before installation?

I could not add it as a requirement since Hosting bundle is not in the list.

Comment: Since this is a module for IIS, this should be installed separately by the server administrator prior to the project deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can install.NET Core Hosting Bundle using the following link:

[Thanks for downloading ASP.NET Core 7.0 Runtime (v7.0.2) - Windows Hosting Bundle Installer!](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)

More information you can refer to this link: [The .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-7.0).